# Что делать если не выводятся объекты определенного url адреса?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

[image: Просто все объекты недвижимости выводит]

https://github.com/Alexey411/aspnetcore

Новостройки и коммерческие не выводится, хотя разместил объекты в этих разделах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public class DBObjects
    {

        public static void Initial(AppDBContent content)
        {

            if (!content.Category.Any())
                content.Category.AddRange(Categories.Select(c => c.Value));

            if (!content.Realty.Any())
            {
                content.AddRange(
                     new Realty
                     {
                         room = "2-комнатная",
                         floor = "4 этаж из 15",
                         squares = "79м²",
                         metro = "м.Алабинская",
                         adress = "улица Митерева, дом 85, кв 128",
                         img = "img/home.jpg",
                         price = 3400000,
                         shortDesc = "Очень хорошая квартира.",
                         longDesc = "Дом находится на южной стороне",
                         phone = "12345678900",
                         isFavourite = true,
                         Category = Categories["Вторички"]
                     },
                    new Realty
                    {
                        room = "1-комнатная",
                        floor = "17 этаж из 38",
                        squares = "49м²",
                        metro = "м.Гагарина",
                        adress = "улица Ленинградская, дом 17, кв 350",
                        img = "img/home2.webp",
                        price = 2600000,
                        shortDesc = "Очень хорошая квартира.",
                        longDesc = "Дом находится на южной стороне",
                        phone = "12345678900",
                        isFavourite = true,
                        Category = Categories["Новостройки"]
                    },
                    new Realty
                    {
                        room = "3-комнатная",
                        floor = "19 этаж из 24",
                        squares = "140м²",
                        metro = "м.Победа",
                        adress = "улица Дальняя, дом 57, кв 192",
                        img = "img/home3.jfif",
                        price = 5600000,
                        shortDesc = "Очень хорошая квартира.",
                        longDesc = "Дом находится на южной стороне",
                        phone = "12345678900",
                        isFavourite = true,
                        Category = Categories["Новостройки"]
                    },
                     new Realty
                     {
                         room = "1-комнатная",
                         floor = "30 этаж из 30",
                         squares = "51м²",
                         metro = "м.Спортивная",
                         adress = "улица Московская шоссе, дом 10, кв 350",
                         img = "img/home4.webp",
                         price = 6600000,
                         shortDesc = "Очень хорошая квартира.",
                         longDesc = "Дом находится на южной стороне",
                         phone = "12345678900",
                         isFavourite = true,
                         Category = Categories["Вторички"]
                     },
                      new Realty
                      {
                          room = "офис",
                          floor = "77 этаж из 78",
                          squares = "251м²",
                          metro = "м.Московское",
                          adress = "улица Московская шоссе, дом 10, офис 350",
                          img = "img/office.jpg",
                          price = 6600000,
                          shortDesc = "Очень хороший офис.",
                          longDesc = "Офис с хорошим ремонтом",
                          phone = "12345678900",
                          isFavourite = true,
                          Category = Categories["Коммерческие"]
                      }
                    );
            }
            content.SaveChanges();

        }
        private static Dictionary<string, Category> category;
        public static Dictionary<string, Category> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                if (category == null)
                {
                    var list = new Category[]
                    {
                         new Category{ categoryName = "Вторички"},
                         new Category{ categoryName = "Новостройки"},
                         new Category{ categoryName = "Коммерческая"},
                         new Category{ categoryName = "Аренда"},
                    };
                    category = new Dictionary<string, Category>();
                    foreach (Category el in list)
                        category.Add(el.categoryName, el);
                }
                return category;
            }
        }
    }

  public class AppDBContent : DbContext
    {
        public AppDBContent(DbContextOptions<AppDBContent> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Realty> Realty { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShopCartItem> ShopCartItem { get; set; }
    }


    public class RealtyController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAllRealty _allRealty;
        private readonly IRealtyCategory _allCategories;

        public RealtyController(IAllRealty iAllRealty, IRealtyCategory iRealtyCat)
        {
            _allRealty = iAllRealty;
            _allCategories = iRealtyCat;
        }

        [Route("Realty/List")]
        [Route("Realty/List/{category}")]
        public ViewResult List(string category, int id)
        {
            string _category = category;
            IEnumerable<Realty> realty = null;
            string currCategory = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
            {
                realty = _allRealty.Realty.OrderBy(i => i.id);
            }
            else
            {
                if (string.Equals("Newbuilding", category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    realty = _allRealty.Realty.Where(i => i.Category.categoryName.Equals("Новостройка")).OrderBy(i => i.id);
                    currCategory = "Новостройки";
                }
                else if (string.Equals("Secondaryschools", category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    realty = _allRealty.Realty.Where(i => i.Category.categoryName.Equals("Вторичка")).OrderBy(i => i.id);
                    currCategory = "Вторички";
                }
                else if (string.Equals("Commercial", category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    realty = _allRealty.Realty.Where(i => i.Category.categoryName.Equals("Коммерческие")).OrderBy(i => i.id);
                    currCategory = "Коммерческая";
                }
                else if (string.Equals("Rent", category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    realty = _allRealty.Realty.Where(i => i.Category.categoryName.Equals("Аренда")).OrderBy(i => i.id);
                    currCategory = "Аренда";
                }

                currCategory = _category;
            }

            var realtyobj = new RealtyListViewModel
            {
                allRealty = realty,
                currCategory = currCategory
            };


            ViewBag.Title = "Недвижимость";


            return View(realtyobj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Правый клик по неотображаемой картинке - "исследовать элемент" и смотрите, что за ссылка у вас на картинку там. Потом сравните ее с рабочей ссылкой на картинку.

Comment: aepot как инспект-элемент может помочь это же html

Comment: `i.Category.categoryName.Equals("Новостройка"))` у вас нет категории с именем `Новостройка`. Поэтому плохо использовать литералы в коде, где этого можно избежать.

Comment: заведите себе `CaregoryId`, числовой, используйте его как путь к категории в URL. И не придется извращаться с `IgnoreCase` - `try { Category c = Categories[category]; realty = _allRealty.Realty.Where(i => i.Category == c).OrderBy(i => i.id); } catch { retun NotFound(); }` или без выброса исключения через `Dictionary.TryGetValue`.

Comment: aepot получается где есть categoryName я должен переименовать в categoryId. Т.е сам categoryName вообще не нужен вообще?

Comment: aepot а откуда вы взяли Categories?

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли, оставьте как есть. Исправили ошибку, и ладно.